# Distorted edges in model rendering xna

Tags: xna-4.0

The edges of my model are not rendered smooth in xna. [See here](http://postimg.org/image/x0g9cdu7v/). What can i do for this, as when designer renders the same model in maya, edges are smooth. And is it possible to render models in xna which provide same results as Vray pugin renders in maya or max.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called anti-aliasing.
Set `PreferMultiSampling` to true in your `Game` class constructor:

```
graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;
```

You can change the level of anti-aliasing by setting the appropriate `MultiSampleType`, for example:

```
graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.MultiSampleType = 
   MultiSampleType.SixteenSamples;
```